# Kinetic energy in "interplanetary" Gravitational potential energy problem?

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, potential

For a system of two **completely stationary** planets both of the same radius and mass, when launching a projectile (e.g. a rocket) from point A on the left planet - assuming we know *U* - minimal kinetic energy needed to reach the planet on the right in a straight path (launched straight towards the other 'planet'),

[image: Launching in a straight line]

would the minimal kinetic energy needed to reach the other planet if the projectile was launched at **an angle** from point A be greater or equal to *U* from above?

e.g.:

[image: Launching at an angle]

Comment: In the first scenario, shouldn't both collide even if velocity was zero..? The gravitational force is always attractive

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - the planets are completely stationary and the question is about an object being launched from point A on the left planet to the right planet - not the planets themselves. e.g. a rocket. I'll edit that in.